# Как получить данные из Intent (не Bundle)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

Надо получить массив байт mTicketByteValue, как это сделать?

P.S. Или value[3] из mMap

[image]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса